# Find the slope at $\theta = \pi/3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

We are given

$r = 2\cos(\theta)$ Find the slope at $\theta = \pi/3$

This is a polar curve.

Why would you find the slope at $dy/dx$ rather than $dr/d\theta$?

Comment: What does slope mean here?

Answer (score 1):

The slope is defined to be $\frac{dy}{dx}$, since it is just "an infiniteseminal slope triangle" ($\lim \limits _{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{x+h-x}$). Ofcourse, the curve is given in polar form, but $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ just defines the change of $r$ respective to $\theta$. (I hope this helps, english is (obviously) not my native language)

Comment: that does help. so $dr/dt$ is defining the curve as in a cartesian plane, when it is supposed to be in polar form?

Comment: Not particularly (actually, the opposite of that). The curve is allowed to be defined using polar form, but the word *slope* always refers to $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: @EricStucky Exactly, $dy/dx$ is _cartesian_ form. By itself $dy/dx$ can easily be replaced by $dr/d\theta$ but this is only in square, cartesian coordinates, _not_ polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

the graph of polar equation $r = 2 \cos \theta$ is a circle centered at $(1,0)$ of unit radius. the point $\theta = \pi/3$ corresponds to $P = (1/2, \sqrt 3/2)$ in cartesian. so the $(0,0), (1,0)$ and $P$ is an equilateral triangle. so the radius makes an angle $2\pi/3$ so the tangent makes $\pi/6$ with the positive $x$-axis. so the slope of the tangent is $tan(\pi/3) = \sqrt 3/3.$